# How should I refer to these two groups of filters?

Tags: filter, faceted-search

On a search results page, there are a bunch of filters that are in two separate levels.

Let's say the first level choices are Wiki, Files, People, Projects, Books, and Everything. The second level are contextual and can include things like Location, Time, Type, etc.

Is there a better name for these two groups than top-level filters and contextual filters?

Answer (score 3):

Wiki, Files, People, Projects, Books, and Everything -> "Sources"

Location, Time, Type -> "Filters" or "Context"

Answer (score 2):

I think its best to have some thing like

**Filter Your Search:**(for Top Level Filters)

**By:**(for contextual filters)

Answer (score 0):

Every filter you described can be abstracted as a search parameter, so one could argue that distinctions like "top-level" and "contextual" are just overhead. If it isn't appropriate to give them all equal footing in a single filter set, you might order them arbitrarily according to what you consider their relative importance.

I suggest this only because your filter set doesn't look huge, but for larger filter sets there are instances where you might find it helpful to sub-divide the options into groups with headings, similar to the sidebar filters you see on Kayak or LinkedIn.